# raspberry Pi 3B+ octoprint TFT screen blacks and becomes unresponsive

Tags: pi-3

i switched from touch ui to Octoprint-TFT because i'm using a 3.5" display, and touch ui just isn't optimized for such a little screen.  My issue is that the touch screen now goes to sleep after about 5 minutes and will not wake up unless i reboot the pi.

I've been searching many solutions, but they call for directories that do not exist in my install. I have the latest xserver installed.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: What is your installation? What directories are you missing? Do you use **Raspbian**?

Comment: Old Octoprint drivers might not work with new stretch 9.  Are you using the following: 
Octopi + Adafruit 2.8" capactive TFT + OctoPrint-TFT review
https://community.octoprint.org/t/octopi-adafruit-2-8-capactive-tft-octoprint-tft-review/2731

Installing OctoPrint and Octoprint-TFT to control your 3D Printer, with a touch screen!  
https://www.crackedconsole.com/community/3-general/wip-installing-and-configuring-octopi-octoprint-for-raspberry-pi-to-control-your-3d-printer/

OctoPrint X desktop environment, then Touch-TFT and its requirements
https://github.com/mcuadros/OctoPrint-TFT